# Retrieve pictures from a Facebook page?

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, graph, facebook-fql, fbml

I want to get the images that members of a Facebook page post. How could I retrieve them?

**I am not talking about a user profile, I am talking about a Facebook Community page.**

I can access the album of a community  page by:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGEID}/photos
```

but how can I access the images that people post on a particular page's wall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGEID}/feed/` has everything on the page's timeline including photos

Comment: Its Asking for an Access Token , Which Access token should be given with which permission and why ? I need to understand this ?

Comment: see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/ and https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ for more info on the permissions model - the Graph API docs list which permissions are needed for different objects/fields/connections in the API